# Match height of absolute td

Tags: css

I am trying to setup a frozen column and the only problem left I have to solve is the heights of the other td's on the same row do not expand to match the height of the absolute positioned td.  Since the text in the frozen header is arbitrary, it could span multiple lines.  **If it weren't absolute positioned then this would force the other td's in that same row to assume the larger height, which is the behavior I would like.**  But since that first td is absolute, then the heights are no longer linked to the other td's in the same row.

**How do I force the other td's in that same row to assume the larger height of the first td?**

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wrms/5/

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;

    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
td {
    margin:0;            

}
div.pivot-container {
    width: calc(100% - 125px);
    overflow-x:scroll;
    margin-left:125px;
    overflow-y:visible;
}
.headcol {
    position:absolute;
    width:125px;
    left:20px; /*must match padding of outer element*/
    top:auto;
}
.long {            
    width: 230px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

<div style="padding-left:20px;">
<div class="pivot-container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol"> kjgh kj ghkj ghkj gkj g2jhfgjhfg</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTJKLZXCVBNM</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUIOFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUVBNM</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYCVBNM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol">5765765785</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPXCVBNM</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYCVBNM</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYCVBNM</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDNM</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `height:100%` seems to work pretty well. Just have to hide the overflow rows somehow. I'll post as answer if you want

Comment: @ZachSaucier 100% on TD?  This fixes the borders but not what I am after.  My issue is with the text in the second row cell running into the next cell, instead of the entire row expanding to accommodate the wrapped text.

Comment: I've used Google Docs Spreadsheets in the past to figure out how to have fixed headers for scrolling content. The solution I implemented based on it wouldn't work in your case, because I trimmed out some of what they were doing.

Comment: @JasonAller Yeh, they use javascript to solve this problem and set explicit inline height to make them match up.

Answer (score 1):

You want the other rows to have the same `height` as the cells in the first column, right? If I understood correctly, you will need to establish the `width` of the whole table using jQuery, so that the `height` will change to what you want too.

If you want, for instance, that all rows be no taller than `26px` (the height of the cells in the first column), then the table's `width` can be changed to match this limit by iterating through the rows and checking the `height` of each, and changing the `width` accordingly, since just indicating it in the css that all rows should be X `height` will not work.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var cont = 0;
    var control = false;
    var wTable = $("table").width();
    do {
        cont = 0;
        $("tr").each(function() {
            h = $(this).height();
            if(h > 26) {
                cont++;
                if(cont == 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        if(cont == 0) {
            control = true;
        }
        else {
            wTable = wTable + 200;
            $("table").width(wTable);
        }
    } while(!control);
    $("tr").height(26);
});
```

This way, we're telling the table to add `200px` to its `width` for every row that it finds taller than `26px`, and once there are no more, it will stop. At the end of the loop we establish the `height` one more time in case some rows ended up being shorter than the first column.

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnLqx/2/), which uses a bit of your original code (I'd recommend testing it directly in your browser, however, since due to JSFiddle's layout it will not display correctly). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to repeat the content from the absolutely positioned td into the last td of the relative td's.  Since I can generate the columns server side, it was easy to repeat the content in another column.   I then used css to set `visibility:hidden' on that last td.  As long as the width of both that hidden td and the absolute td are the same, then they will have the same height, and those both parts of the row, the absolute and relative, will have the same height.

It has a negative side affect of still taking up space at the end of the table, so it might affect the sizing of outer elements.